# vb.net dynamic names of classes / reflection

Tags: vb.net, object, methods, dynamic, attributes

I want to use a configuration I get from elsewhere to choose a class to dynamically instanciate and then what method to dynamically choose to get a FoodItem.

Let's assume we have the following classes available:

```
Class Orange
    inherits treefruits ( which inhertis tree -> which inherits basicLife)
    color as string
    shadeOfOrange as string

    function eat
    function pickAndPeel as FoodItem

END Class

Class Potatoe
   inherits vegetables ( which inhertis plants -> which inherits basicLife)
   color as string
   hasWorm as boolean

   function eat
   function cook as FoodItem
   function chipAndFry as FoodItem -> This is where config wants me to go.
   function makeWedges as FoodItem
End Class

Class frozenPizza
   inherits IndustrialFoods ( which inherits ... which inherits ... which inherits basicLife)
   size as integer
   temperature as integer

   function eat
   function bakeInOven as FoodItem
   function heatInMicrowave as Fooditem
   function grillInSmoker as Fooditem
End Class

configString as String = "Potatoe-chipAndFry"
//Here has to come the Part which instanciates a new potatoe and then runs it's chipAndFry method
```

As you can see, they have similar functions and  attributes, but they aren't identical. The same goes for bananas, apples etc. The List is too long to be in switch-case - at least it is too long to be easily maintainable.

Thanks to two comments I've learned about reflection and I found an example which covers the dynamic use of a method and a class, which should be what I need to seperate my config string and get going ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29#C# )

As for the methods, I think I understand how to get the "ChipAndFry" part of the config string to work. I don't how to dynamically instanciate a class yet (I don't get the "complete.classpath.and.Foo" from the wikipedia example), but that's what I am working on tomorrow.

Comment: I assume both classes inherit from FoodItem?  I would put the common functions on the base class (and pick a spelling for peal/peel).  The base class could have a `Shared Function Harvest(thing As String) As FoodItem` and put your switch statement there.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is not where to build the switch case. I have the string "orange-pick" and no object at this point. But I know (by getting that string) that there is a class "orange" which will have a "pick" method. It could be "frozenPizza-bakeInOven", "frozenPizza-heatInMicrowave" as well as dozens (and it's not like 2 or 3 dozens, its more like 10 dozens now, still growing) of other combinations.

Comment: Ah.  Google for .NET Reflection.  That will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: You could consider using some sort of factory or factory-style arrangement, where you use a dictionary to map from string to thing-that-gives-you-an-instance (which might in turn be built using reflection to find classes that fit a particular profile).  You might then find your method directly using reflection, or, depending on usage, you might want to look them up up-front, as reflection can be pretty slow.

Comment: The good thing is that The functions delivering the FoodItems contain everything I need to have my output, so performance shouldn't be an issue.
But relection seems to be exactly what I am looking for, in fact the wikipedia-article answers question 2, so I have to get my get around the "instanciate a class" stuff and as I understand you @Craig I can do that with relection, too.
Thank you both!

Comment: I gather that this is a learning exercise, but you should be aware that this is working against the grain of OO programming, specifically polymorphism. Instead of different functions returning a fooditem, conventionally you would have a 'prepare' or 'cook' or s/t function in your base class, which is implemented differently in each derived class as appropriate.

Comment: No, it is not. It is a batch-job which is gets a list of strings and then has to do stuff. The stuff is has to do depends on what the string says.